# Loader like this with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Please, can you checkout http://svpply.com , move the pointer on a image and click `+` when it appears. If you're careful you can see a very nice loader when you've clicked `+`, and after some moments appear a `v`.

How can I implement something like that? In that process there's not "white view" between the three step (`+`, loading, `v`). Ideas?

Actually I've this code:

```
$(".add_button").live("click", function() {
    var element = $(this),
        data = "id=" + this.id;

    element.css("background-image", "url(/media/images/loader.gif)")

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/product/add/",
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            element.css("background-image", "")
            element.removeClass("add_button").addClass("del_button");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

But between the three steps I see an ugly "white image". Why?

**UPDATE**

Now I've:

```
$(".add_button").live("click", function() {
    var element = $(this),
        data = "id=" + this.id;

    element.removeClass("add_button").addClass("spinner");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/product/add/",
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            element.removeClass("spinner").addClass("del_button");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

But still the same problem. Unfortunately I cannot find the interested source in the svpply source code.

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="add_button" id="id"></div>
```

Comment: *How can I implement something like that?* Yes, you can. What have you tried so far? We can show you where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of svpply.com yet?

Comment: @Sparky672 Sincerely I cannot find the interested source, can you help me please?

Comment: Fred: We want to see code and an attempt, not just an extra sentence.

Comment: @Switz You're right. Check my update.

Comment: Ack, it's a terrible UI!  It's synched to match the negative of my x-axis so it avoids the mouse pointer, making it very frustrating to try to click on it.

Comment: @Kirk Woll Yes I know, I'm not interested on that, only in the effect when you click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yessss, this is a good question :)

So basically it has to do with [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and the different kind of settings!  You need to use `ajax:beforeSend` and `ajax:success` (or `ajax:complete` if you're doing more loading after `success`).  Which means you can do something like (assuming your button is wrapped in a form)

```
$(".add_button").parent("form").bind("ajax:beforeSend",function(e,data,status,xhr) {
        $("#someDiv").append("<img id='loading' src='url/to/loading/gif'></img>");
        // and any other things you want to do like removing the button or disabling it
});
```

That function will execute BEFORE the client (your computer) sends the request to the server.  You can also add a lot of stuff in there and modify the option to request you are actually sending to the server!

Then you can have

```
$(".add_button").parent("form").bind("ajax:success",function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        $("#loading").remove();
        // and any other things like adding your del button
});
```

Which is called after the server sends back the object to the client for you to play with, in which case you can remove your `#loading` img and do other cool things!

I really suggest you reading on the link and completely understand how AJAX works, and how the client interacts with the server.  Once you understand that, you can do a lot of cool things like this!  Good luck.

EDIT

You can check out a working example of this (which doesn't use a loading gif but instead disables input) at [this prototype](http://whitespace.heroku.com/) I'm building.  Click on the animating circle and try to submit a comment.  You'll notice that after you hit enter, the comment input box is disabled until the comment is rendered back on your screen!

In your case, your code would look like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/product/add/",
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function(msg) {
        // do the stuff you want to do
    },
    success: function(result) {
        element.removeClass("spinner").addClass("del_button");
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. My button isn't wrapped in a form. Checkout my new update.